# Generate SOAP from sql serve database in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-services, soap

I want to create a SOAP answer when calling a web service written in asp.net with some data that are taken from a database managed by sql server. I'm here to ask you some example/tutorials case I didn't find something... appropriate.

What i've done so far : I've created the link between the database and my web service. I'm now able to display the list of items that are in the database in a web page. Now, how to switch from that display to a SOAP format ?

Just to give ideas, here is my simple code :

For the web page :

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) %> |
            <%= Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.USER_ID) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.LOCATION_ID) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.INVENTORY_ID) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.COMMENT) %>
        </td>
    </tr>

<% } %>
```

Where the item.SOMETHING are the name of my fields.

Could you provide me some example to help me to understant how to do what I want ?
Thanks !

Comment: So, if i understnd well, you need to create a web service that connects to db and return data?

Comment: This will help a lot.http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/327420/WCF-REST-Service-with-JSON

Comment: Ok i'll check that, witch from JSON to SOAP should be easy since it's the same derivate from XML (I think at first look). But it's harder to find some tutos on the list of a database content in a SOAP or JSON format...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for thoses that have the same questions, here is a tuto i've found that cover a lot of things :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/cc668796.aspx

It's in french but it's quiet complete and well explained.